# Insert image file path into PostgreSQL database

Tags: php, android, postgresql

I have a mobile application that sends some data to my PHP web service. The data consists of some textual items and a base64 encoded string (which will be decoded into an image).

I want to store the textual data into some data columns and then a final text column containing the file path to the uploaded image. I have a directory called `usersImages/`, which is where I would like to store all images received by the user, but when I upload the data, my PHP script currently doesn't insert anything into the database.

**PHP file:**

```
$conn = pg_connect("database_credentials");
/* GET DATA */
$name = $_POST['name'];
$s_name = pg_escape_string($name);
$description = $_POST['desc'];  
$s_desc = pg_escape_string($description);
$latitude = $_POST['lat'];
$longitude = $_POST['lng'];
$project = $_POST['project'];

$encoded_photo = $_POST['snap'];
echo $encoded_photo;
$photo = base64_decode($encoded_photo);
header('Content-Type: bitmap; charset=utf-8');
$file = fopen('usersImages/test.jpg', 'wb');
fwrite($file, $photo);
fclose($file);

$res = pg_query("INSERT INTO records (name, description, latitude, longitude, project, imagepath) VALUES ('$s_name', '$s_desc', '$latitude', '$longitude', '$project', '$file')");
```

**What I want to do:**

I want all the data to be stored as text with the final column `imagepath` containing the path to the image I have just uploaded, but I'm having no success with this at the moment. Any ideas?

Comment: As there is the risk of name collision, I would not use a human given name as the file name but an unique identifier in instead using the [uuid-ossp](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/uuid-ossp.html) module.

Comment: @ClodoaldoNeto thank you for your advice. I am purely testing out code at the moment, the user will enter their own filename on the  mobile application and it will be assigned a unique id.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem you are running into is for the "imagepath" column you are storing the $file variable which is `fopen('usersImages/test.jpg', 'wb');`. You cannot store a function call into a column cell, instead you should presumably be storing a data-type that would suit your needs (since you want to store a path-string a varchar should work fine).

What I assume you would like to do is just store the path for instance:

```
$filePath = "usersImages/test.jpg";
$res = pg_query("INSERT INTO records (name, description, latitude, longitude, project, imagepath) VALUES ('$s_name', '$s_desc', '$latitude', '$longitude', '$project', '$filePath')");
```

(As long as you are properly connected to your database this method should work)

Might I even further suggest that you store just the variable name to save space and hardcode the variables that are always the same.... for instance if the folder is always the same and the image type is always jpg you can just store
`$filePath = "test";` and change your loading code with the hard-coded variables and not just a database query.

As for your other question for actually uploading the image to your website, that is difficult to tell you an exact answer because you did not provide the relevant code; but it looks like you are getting a false file due to an improper uploading technique. You should try something like this instead of the fopen,fwrite,fclose method.

```
<input type="file" name="file" id="file"> // In your form (seperate from PHP)
$filePath = "userImages/test.jpg";  //setting file path
$success = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], $filePath); //actually storing the file into your file-system into the selected path
```

Comment: thanks but still hasn't worked. Could you provide a code edit with writing the uploaded and decoded image to the `$filepath` variable?

Comment: @DanielD Is the filePath variable being properly stored in your data-base? Also are you stating that you are unable to save the file onto your website file-system?

Comment: the filePath variable is NOT being written to my database. The image `test.jpg` appears in my chosen directory but is of 0kb size and the `PostGreSQL` database remains blank.

Comment: @DanielD Alright since you are unable to store that variable properly I assume you are not connected properly... Are you able to store other variables in your database on each upload attempt?

Comment: If I comment out the code concerning the filepath/image then yes the textual data is inserted successfully.

Comment: @DanielD Alright, are you at least able to store a variable like $test = "test"; into that database cell; If not your cell may be accessed improperly. On the other hand if you are able to store that variable you can use the other method I described; but if you prefer I can try and find another method that stores the entire link.

Comment: Storing the entire link would be preferred for the requirements set out on the project. I simply wish to insert all the textual data followed by the image path which will point to the uploaded/decoded image.

Comment: @DanielD I can understand the preference of storing the entire link. But to deduce why your error is occurring it would be helpful to know that you are able to store a simple string in that specific cell first. Because if you can then it is a syntax problem with the variable content. Also what is the data-type of the cell in your data-base varchar, text, etc?

Comment: The data type of the column is VARCHAR(255).

Comment: @DanielD Interesting, varchar can store "/" and "." so I don't see why storing "usersImages/test.jpg" would be an issue. You said when you commented out some code the rest of the information was stored properly. What exactly did you comment out?

Comment: `/*$encoded_photo = $_POST['snap'];
 echo $encoded_photo;
        $photo = base64_decode($encoded_photo);
 $file = fopen('usersImages/test.jpg', 'wb');
 fwrite($file, $photo);
 fclose($file);*/` and I can insert a sample string.

Comment: @DanielD Alright so now with that commented out we know where the error is; are you able to store the full path link with the two lines of code I provided in my answer when that is commented out? `$filePath = "usersImages/test.jpg";
$res = pg_query("INSERT INTO records (name, description, latitude, longitude, project, imagepath) VALUES ('$s_name', '$s_desc', '$latitude', '$longitude', '$project', '$filePath')");`

Comment: When I look at the data in my database the imagepath column has the value `usersImages/test/jpg` using your two lines of code however within the `usersImages` directory itself test.jpg does not exist. Also, I have not edited the parameters so they are still `'uploaded_file'` and `'tmp_name'` is that correct to do that?

Comment: @DanielD I do not know if the second slash was a typo; but I assume it may be for the moment. As for uploading the file in your file-system, if that example didn't work try replacing the "uploaded_file" with "file" and make sure that "userImages" is a direct sub-folder of the submission page.